# Need to use position:fixed but still need element in flow. How to do it?

Tags: html, css, css-position

**Scenario:**

In HTML, I have 2 element (top bar and images). The top bar need to be
at `position:fixed` (which will break the flow, I understand that). And
the 2nd element has `margin-top` to push down the image after the
"top bar". This has no issue until I minimised my browser width, the
content in the "top bar" push the container height and overlap the 2nd
element, which is the image. And this look ugly.

Anyway to have the 2nd element in flow with the 1st element, so that no matter how I minimised my browser width, the 2nd element is
smart enough to push down.

**Code: CSS**

```
.TopBar {                                   /* 1st Element */
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    padding:10px;   
}
.TopBar > div {
    color:white;
}

.carousel {                                 /* 2nd Element */
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:73px;
}
.carousel_img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Problem:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, you can't force `position:fixed` to flow, so there isn't an answer to your question to do it the way you want.

But the way you describe the problem, it's about supporting different browser sizes. If that's the case, then it sounds to me as if media queries are the answer to your problem.

CSS supports `@media { ... }` blocks, which allow you to specify styles that only come into play at certain browser sizes. So in order to solve your problem, you need to find out what browser width causes the layout to change (resize very slowly; it will flip out at a specific size), and write a media query that changes your stylesheet for sizes lower than that.

Without (a lot) more detail of your layout, I can't really give you specific code, but there are a lot of resources available online to learn about media queries if you don't already use them.

It's also worth noting that `position:fixed` can often be troublesome at small browser sizes, so much so that a lot of mobile browsers deliberately didn't even support it for some time. That's changed now, but it can still cause layout gremlins, so you may want to use the media query to switch it off entirely in low-width browsers.

Comment: Yea..you are right, the position:fixed and the other properties of it do cause a lot of issue when the page get more element in it. I haven't really learned how to use the @media, but let me check out. Actually my intention is quite straight forward, i have multiple element (img, div) on the index page, as I scroll down, the navigation bar, should always stay on the top, for user to able to access to it anytime wherever there are on the page. Apart from media, is there really no other option? Thanks.

Comment: There may be other options, but @media is almost certain to be the best option -- quite simply because often it's sensible to have some of the layout look different at different browser sizes. Media queries really are quite easy to get the hang of and they give you so much flexibility to tailor your design to different browser sizes, so they're well worth the effort to learn.

Comment: Hi Spudley, do you mind help to view the source file in the attached google drive. I cant figure out the reason that the #topnav can behaviour like a position:sticky or fixed, when the css is having position:relative....[Click Here to access to the HTML file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzbdjY-H_HzZTC1Rci1nY0F4VFU?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to achieve, there's a workaround to achieve similar results.

First, you effectively can't make your TopBar behaving like a flowing bloc element with position: fixed. So, let's make static.

The "fixed" behaviour will be provide by setting the body properties

```
    body {
  /* NOTICE the vertical flex box, makes the height adjust 
     automaticaly (no need to toggle)*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh; /* Restrain the body to the window height */
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Prevent scrollbar on body */
}

.TopBar {
  display: block; /* Blocks have 100% widht by default, don't need to 
                     specify */
  padding: 10px;
  position: static; /* No need to specify, it's the default value */
  /* Helpers to make the TopBar easier to track */
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* This is not part of the solution, it's only to make the height inversely proportional to window width
     e.g. make it grow while the other decrease 
  */
  height: calc(200px - 10vw);
}

/* 
    Just under the TopBar, lets place a container element that will act 
    as scrolling window 
*/

.container {
  height: 100vh; /* max-height is superfluous because of the overflow. */
  /* This will simply make the scrolling on the container instead of the body */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.TopBar {
  /* 1st Element */
}
.TopBar > div {
  color: white;
}
/* simply to display some text */
p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

Place your carousel inside the container and voilà! No need for position nor z-index fiddling. TopBar and container are flowing and the former will "push" the later.

That being said, some media query adjustments wouldn't hurt. According to your picture, elements in your TopBar are inlines (inline or inline blocks). You should consider making them "block". Flex-boxes would also worth some consideration.

Hope this help

Comment: I have tried your comment, it doesnt solve my problem. when I minimise the browser, top navigation bar and the image still overlap each other. But I get your idea, you are using the overflow to hide the overflow content if the size of the browser is being minimised....Thanks for your help...great idea.

Comment: The `overflow: hide` on **body** is to prevent scrolling on the entire body. The `overflow-y: scroll` makes it in the container... 
You may haven't apply what explain. It works, it's an old (and well known) approach. I'll get back to you with a code pen if I have some free time (I'm writing from work).

Comment: @BSS See this code Pen for yourself

https://codepen.io/iRouge/pen/yXpXGz?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Respond to answer given by Spudley on using the @media to solve the issue, I have try to find some page that has the effect of "fixed" & overflow element, and inspect the code by viewing it through web editor. And this is what I get. I slowly delete all the CSS and related element one by one till I got the "fixed" not working. And while the  is still set on position:relative, there is a CSS that attached to it, which when I remove it, the "fixed" effect was gone.

reference URL:

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp

I filter the source file:

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzbdjY-H_HzZTC1Rci1nY0F4VFU?usp=sharing
```

Screen Capture of the coding that solve my problem (I guess)

> [Click Here to see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXBCy.png)